# Minimum/maximum element in a balanced binary search time in O(1) time

Tags: c++, algorithm, dictionary, tree, binary-search-tree

I know we can find minimum/maximum in a binary search tree in O(logn) time. But map in c++ gives us the minimum/maximum in constant time. We can find minimum element in a map using the [map::begin](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/begin/)  and maximum using [map::rbegin](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/rbegin/) . Both these operation takes constant time. Can anyone suggest a method that makes finding minimum/maximum O(1) ?

Comment: Store two more pointers along with the root.

Comment: std::map is usually implemented with a search tree, so what you mean is a std::unordered_map which implemented via a hashmap. Since a hashmap doesnt care about an order we can't find the min in O(1). When you want to get the min/max in O(1) without deleting it I would recommend you a min-heap or a max-heap

Comment: @Exagon: I mean the ordered_map. You can take a look at map::rbegin and map::begin.

Comment: @molbdnilo : Since deletion can also be frequent, changing pointers will again take O(logn) time.

Comment: @Shivam Mitra yes but the ordered map is usually implemented via a binary search tree, which has like you said O(logn) except you are storing extra pointers so min and max in the root

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ map is not implemented by BST. It is implemented by Red Black Tree. If you want to find min/max in BST by O(1),you can store the two pointers to the leftmost node and rightmost node in the tree.
Else, you can use minheap or maxheap to find out min/max in O(1).

Comment: Yes, we can do that. But deletion of the min/max node changes the pointers. That will still take O(logn) to find the new minimum/maximum.

Comment: No, It can be done in O(1) again. Even if you delete the min node (suppose) during deletion itself you can update your min pointer to inorder successor of the min node. So, at any point of time you get your min,max in O(1) . You can say that you are increasing your complexity in Deletion. But that will still be O(logn) .

Comment: A Red Black Tree is also a Binary Search Tree just saying

Comment: But it is balanced. Normally when we talk about a BST, we don't consider the balancing part

Comment: Normally if we talk about BST, we should always think of it as a Balanced BST because keeping a Search Tree Balanced is a constant time operation.